# Bigcommerce cart 422: Missing required fields error

Tags: php, laravel, api, cart, bigcommerce

I'm using Laravel to consume the Bigcommerce V3 API.

I have ben able to succesfully create a new cart. But when trying to add an item to it, I keep getting a `422: Missing required fields` error.

I'm making my request trough Guzzle like this:

```
return json_decode($this->client->getRestClient()
            ->post('carts/'.$cartId.'/items?include=line_items.physical_items.options', [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'json' => [
                    'line_items' => [
                        'product_id' => 86,
                        'quantity' => 1
                    ],
                ],
            ])
            ->getBody())
        ->data;
```

The product I'm trying to add has no options or modifiers, so I don't understand what could wrong with my request. According to the [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/carts/cart-items/addcartlineitem), this should be all that's needed.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? I tried contacting support, but to no avail.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example shows an api key: `X-Auth-Token: {access_token}` Are you forgetting to add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line_items` is an array of objects. Try wrapping your product data in an object.

Like this:

```
'line_items' => [
  {
    'quantity' => 1,
    'product_id' => 86
  }
]
```

Comment: Making it
```
'line_items' => [
                        [
                            'product_id' => 86,
                            'quantity' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
```
did the trick.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `line_items` field needs to have an array of objects, like this:

```
[
    {
        "product_id":86,
        "quantity":1
    }
]
```